# Timer goes crazy when using setInterval inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've been trying to learn the fundamentals of React and tried something like this which made the code go crazy. It looks like all the digits change wildly fast starting from the initial one and after a while the browser gives warnings like

> "setInterval" is taking 205ms

Tried adding timer as a dependency and even returning it. It's all a little confusing to me. Can someone please explain to me in depth what's happening here?

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)

  useEffect(()=>{

    setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer(timer + 1)
    }, 1000)
  },[timer])

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Timer : {timer}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please explain

Comment: If your `useEffect` dependency array contains the state you are setting inside it, it will make an infinite loop, because each time the state is set, `useEffect` will be called again. There no need to add it there, just change `[timer]` per `[]` to make it empty of dependencies.

Comment: Consider also accessing to your `prev` state to set the new `timer` like: `setTimer(prev => prev + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `timer` as dependency form the `useEffect` otherwise it will **recreate** another *interval* every time the `timer` gets updated.

You may also want to clear the interval using `clearInterval` in the cleanup of the hook i.e. when component unmounts (in this case).

And, as [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you need to do `setTimer(prev => prev + 1)` to read the previous (the latest state) and increment to it.

```js
function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prev) => prev + 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id)
    }
  }, [])

  return <h1>Timer : {timer}</h1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: You don't need to use a ref for the setinterval id. It could just be a local variable in the useEffect function closure.

Comment: I know how they work, thank you. I just think it's much easier to use `setTimeout` in this case, no need to clean anything - https://jsfiddle.net/4howanL2/3/